# TABLEAU - Joins on the fly on raw data

Tags: join, filter, group-by, tableau-api

I have been trying to perform joins on the fly in Tableau to perform some online computation - with no luck so far.

I wonder if any of you is aware of a way to achieve this?

I have a typical transactions dataset ("MYDATA"), with user ID (user's identifier), transaction date (when the transaction occurred), and purchases (the transactions). Something like:

```
ID    TRANSACTION DATE   PURCHASES
123   20/03/2020           1
123   22/03/2020           4
234   20/03/2020           10
234   22/03/2020           1
345   22/03/2020           5
```

#### What I would like to achieve is to add to it a variable with the SUM of PURCHASES by ID (say field "PURCHASES PER ID").

#### Then, critically, I'd like to make this computation update dynamically as I filter by different values in TRANSACTION DATE from the UI.

Ultimately I'd like to create a chart displaying the count of users (field "ID") in each value  of the field "PURCHASES PER ID" (like bins), where "PURCHASES PER ID" is re-computed according to the date ranges selected in the worksheet.

Something like:

Case 1 : FILTER Transaction date = 20/03/2020 AND 22/03/2020

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      count OF ID    | SUM of PURCHASES |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         11       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Case 2 : FILTER Transaction date = 20/03/2020

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      count OF ID    | SUM of PURCHASES |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I'd expect this to be doable in Tableau, as I'm able to it with a much more simple (and cheaper) tool like Google Data Studio.

In Data Studio I'd simply do a join between "MYDATA" and the sum of PURCHASES grouped by ID - using ID as KEY. Then, I'd able to use that calculated sum of purchases as a dimension, and count the IDs in it.

Are you aware of a way to achieve the same in Tableau?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Think I got it.

My solution was:

Columns: ({FIXED [ID]: SUM([PURCHASES])})

Rows: CNTD(ID)

Filters: Add TRANSACTION DATE to Context

This allows me to achieve the view I wanted to.